# pasar variables de php a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hola quisiera un poco de ayuda con esta pregunta.
tengo este codigo php pero me gustaria pasarlo solo a javascript es posible

```js
$referr = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$keyface  = 'facebook';
$desdefacebook = strpos($referr, $keyface);
if ($desdefacebook === false) {
echo "No viene de facebook :D ";
} 
elseif ($desdefacebook !== false) {
   echo "Si viene de facebook";
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres pasar exactamete? todo el codigo?

Comment: No comprendo que intentas hacer. Quieres saber si el usuario fué redirigido desde Facebook en el cliente web (con javascript)  o quieres enviar al cliente el resultado de tu codigo?

Comment: "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];" esto y  lo que no funcione en javascript com esto "strpos" @ArieCwHat

Comment: saber si el ususario fue dirigido desde facebook  usando javascript @ArieCwHat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí les dejo una forma que me funciona gracias por sus respuestas .

```
<div style="display:none;" id="nombre">algo</div>
<script>
var x = document.referrer;
if(x.indexOf("facebook")>0){
document.getElementById("nombre").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas.

Para obtener el `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` pero en javascript, puedes acceder a la propiedad "referrer" de la página en la que estas, de la siguiente forma:

```
var result = document.referrer.split( '/' ).indexOf("www.facebook.com");;
if (result >= 0){
    console.log("viene desde fb");
} else {
    console.log("no viene desde fb");
}
```

Comment: se puede usar solo con la palabra facebook sin usar "www.facebook.com"

Comment: depende, si buscas dentro de "referrer" completo con index of, sería resultado positivo en un string como "http:// pagina.com/phishing/facebook". Quizá debas validar la posición en la que se busca "facebook".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me a sido muy util

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `document.referrer` para obtener la url desde donde vino el usuario. Quedaría algo como:

```
var referr = document.referrer; 

if(referr.indexOf('facebook')!==-1) {
  console.log('NO viene desde FB');
} else {
  console.log('Viene desde FB');
}
```

Obviamente `document.referrer` es un string vacío si el usuario escribió la url a mano o llegó desde sus favoritos.

**PD**: la respuesta de @ArieCwHat es más correcta porque considera sólo el host facebook. En mi respuesta podría haber falsos positivos si el resto de la URI contiene esa palabra. Peeero, me limité a transformar tu código, que tiene la misma salvedad.

Comment: gracias entiendo